# SQL Case statement with aggregate functions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to perform a case statement where if all records for a particular Project contain a certain value for all teams then the project will be categorized as how I see fit. Something along the lines of

```
case when (COUNT(team_Name) = (SUM(status = 'Completed')) then 'Complete'
case when (COUNT(team_Name) = (SUM(status = 'On Hold')) then 'On hold'
case when (COUNT(team_Name) = (SUM(status = 'Pending')) then 'Pending'
else 'In Progress' end
```

so I am trying to get the sum of (status = 'Completed'), which I believe is a boolean statement to match the count of team_names. My thought process is that if the count of team names and number of 'Completed' status are the same, then the project will be considered 'Complete'.

So the select grouping goes Project -> Team -> Status -> result of case statement. I want to use the above case statement in a join so the case statement results aggregates on a Project level or something along those lines.

However, my syntax seems to be a little off with the statement above and I can't get the query to run with this. I get an incorrect syntax error near '='. for the (status = 'Completed') side.

Is this even possible in SQL or is there something I need to change.

Comment: So there are many statusses and only if they all equal, then this is considered the project status? Otherwise, i.e. if one status is 'Complete' and one is 'On hold' for instance, then the project is supposed to be 'Abandoned'? And you compare the count with the count of all non-null team names? Somehow that doesn't seem to make much sense.

Comment: Actually it would make sense to call it 'In Progress' if that case...I just made up random statuses for this question, but you're right in wouldn't make much sense in that scenario. All teams will be operating in a project, so for project 1 if there are 3 teams, and they are all currently 'Pending' then the project status is in 'pending'. If theres a mix of statuses, then I can name that to an 'In Progress' or something.

Comment: So there is one record per sub-project or task with a status and a team name, right? So there are no NULLs in team_Name and COUNT(team_Name) is COUNT(*) actually, right?

Comment: That is correct. 1 per subproject with a status and team name. There are no null values. The select query itself is Project,team_name,status, custom_column where i want to place the result of the case statement. I edited my post to make it a little more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
case COUNT(team_Name) 
    when SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'Completed' THEN 1 END) then 'Complete'
    when SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'On Hold' THEN 1 END)   then 'On Hold'
    when SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'Pending' THEN 1 END)   then 'Pending'
       else 'Abandoned' end
```

Comment: Pretty close to what I am looking for, but because these teams are associated to a Project, the new column is just bringing in whatever value 'status' is bringing in. Let me know if I am being unclear or vague...Trying to get better at SQL.

Comment: @user3348557: Hamlet's answer solves your syntax issue. So if there are any more issues with your statement, then you should show us the statement along with the results from Hamlet's solution and the desired results.

Comment: That's fair enough. Guess I'll ask another question. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I got it to work by using this in a join statement and reducing my select fields to just project and the case statement above. Thanks a lot once again!

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this using Decode Function. It works like a IF-THEN-ELSE conditon.

With an Example for you:

```
Select YourFieldAliasName =
CASE TEAM_ID
    WHEN 'Completed' THEN 'Complete'
WHEN 'On Hold' THEN 'Complete'
WHEN 'Pending' THEN 'Pending'
    ELSE 'Abandoned'
END
```

Here Abandoned is else case, if all the rest of conditions fails.